# Is there a built-in way to get the current URL without any query parameters?

Tags: angularjs, url, location-provider

If my URL is `http://www.something.com/foo/bar/index.html?color=yellow&animal=rat`, it seems as though:

- `$location.path()` will return `foo/bar/index.html`
- `$location.absUrl()` will return `http://www.something.com/foo/bar/index.html?color=yellow&animal=rat`
- `$location.url()` will return `foo/bar/index.html?color=yellow&animal=rat`

Is there any function which will return `http://www.something.com/foo/bar/index.html`?

Or do I have to construct that myself with functions like protcol, host, port, etc. (or strip the query params off myself)?

Comment: When I did this, I had to construct it myself. I would be pleased if that weren't necessary.

Comment: Isn't $location.absUrl() returning what you want or why aren't you just stripping off the ? at the end?

Comment: $location.absUrl() has the query parameters ("?color=yellow&animal=rat") on the end.  Easy enough to strip off but I was just wondering if there was a built-in function since they seem to have functions for just about everything else.

Comment: Are you opposed to using $window service? $window.location.origin + $window.location.pathname should get you what you want.

Comment: It seems the only way is to construct it by yourself.

Comment: As of the date of this comment, the mozilla developer docs state location.origin is "an experimental API and should not be used in production code"

Comment: also try $location.$$path and $location.$$url

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you have to construct it yourself. Not that you were asking how to construct it, but for those who are wondering:

```
var url = $location.absUrl().split('?')[0]
```

Comment: also try $location.$$path and $location.$$url

Comment: @Jamy How do I get this http://localhost/mac/app/pages/company2?companyId=1286      , right now I am just getting http://localhost/mac/app/pages/company2

Comment: @BadshahTracker try this: `var url = $location.absUrl();`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location - The `$location` service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on the `window.location`) and makes the URL available to your application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into $location service and changes to `$location` are reflected into the browser address bar.

Answer (score 9):

Not that this eliminates the need to construct it by yourself, just another way to do the same.
If you use window.location object, you can just say 
window.location.origin+window.location.pathname

window.location object has

```
host:"localhost.abc.com:8080"
hostname:"localhost.abc.com"
href:"http://localhost.abc.com:8080/quickpick/repossessions/?displayStr=Repossessions&from=%2F&page=1"(whole url)

origin:"http://localhost.abc.com:8080"
pathname:"/quickpick/repossessions/"
port:"8080"
protocol:"http:"
```