# How to get last part of URL, ignoring any GET parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm expecting URLs in this for:

```
/user/username
```

but end users can also add whatever get parameters they want, like so:

```
/user/username?foo=bar
```

With that said, using AngularJS, what's the preferred way for me to get just the `username` (which appears after `/user/`) without anything else after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `$location` service and its `.path()` method, then use a regular `split()` and indexing.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's a dedicated function for it but it seems easy enough to pull it out of the string with the query.
Get the path with $location.path() and then both of these does the job for you.

```
url.substring(6, (url.indexOf('?') != -1 ? url.indexOf('?') : url.length))

url.split('/')[2].split('?')[0]
```

Same question here: [Is there a built-in way to get the current URL without any query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505577/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-get-the-current-url-without-any-query-parameters)

Comment: `$location.path()` does not return the search parameters, there's no need dealing with the `?`

Answer (score 0):

you can use window.location or $location service to get the path and then using split function 
like this

```
var url = "/user/username?foo=bar";
var check = url.split('/user/');
var username = check[1].split('?');
console.log(username[0]);
```

you can find username by applying multiple split on your url. hope this is what you want.

Comment: It's good that you want to help, but please avoid repetition of an already existing answer.